# How to set a category to a Liferay Web Content in Java?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

In Liferay 7, I have a Web Content, a vocabulary and a category.
How to set the category to the Web Content?

I wrote this code:

```
article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle(...);
category = AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.addCategory(...);

AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.setAssetEntryAssetCategories(
    article.getPrimaryKey(), new long[]{category.getPrimaryKey()});
```

At execution no error, but the category does not show up on the edit page of the created Web Content:

[image]

The category has been created successfully, but the Web Content does not get that category assigned.

What am I doing wrong?

*I have also tried `addAssetEntryAssetCategories`, `addAssetEntryAssetCategory`, `addAssetCategoryAssetEntry`: same problem.*

Comment: Did you see an entry in asset entry table?

Comment: @YuVi: Yes, the Web Content exists in the `AssetEntry` table, and the category exists in the `AssetCategory` table.

Comment: Sorry! I meant the mapping table "AssetEntries_AssetCategories"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using any of these 2 functions to add category:

```
addAssetEntryAssetCategory(long entryId, long categoryId);
addAssetEntryAssetCategories(long entryId, long[] categoryIds);
```

In your code, you are using primary_key, however, as per documentation you should be using entry id and category id.  So your function call should look like this:

```
AssetEntry entry = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.fetchEntry(JournalArticle.class.getName(),  article.getResourcePrimKey());

AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.addAssetEntryAssetCategory(
    entry.getEntryId(), category.getCategoryId());
```

Since 7.0, they removed the getEntryId method from JournalArticle you would need an additional call to fetch it. There is a `update` method which you may also consider that would do this in single call. I'm still using 6.2 and catching up 7 :).

Please note categories are designed for use by administrators, not regular users.

Comment: I just changed the call to `addAssetEntryAssetCategories` and executed again. Same problem: The Web Content still has zero category.

Comment: And same problem with `addAssetEntryAssetCategory`.

Comment: `JournalArticle.getEntryId` does not exist in Liferay 7, did you mean `article.getId()` maybe? But it does not work either.

Comment: Remember you are populating the mapping table between AssetEntry and AssetCategory. So, you actually need the entry id. I updated the code to fetch that id for you.

Comment: Wonderful, that works! Thanks a lot for the mapping table tip.

Answer (score 0):

I am using liferay 7.1 dxp

In my case I have to update category of journal article or web content using program.
In order to achieve this I have to use assetEntryAssetCategoryRel class.
to access this and related class first I added dependency to my build.gradle file

compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.asset.entry.rel.api", version: "1.1.0"

```
List<AssetEntryAssetCategoryRel> assetEntryAssetCategoryRelsByAssetEntryId = AssetEntryAssetCategoryRelLocalServiceUtil.
                    getAssetEntryAssetCategoryRelsByAssetEntryId(assetEntry.getEntryId());
if(assetEntryAssetCategoryRelsByAssetEntryId!=null && !assetEntryAssetCategoryRelsByAssetEntryId.isEmpty()){
                    AssetEntryAssetCategoryRel assetEntryAssetCategoryRel = assetEntryAssetCategoryRelsByAssetEntryId.get(0);
                    assetEntryAssetCategoryRel.setAssetCategoryId(assetCategory.getCategoryId());
                    assetEntryAssetCategoryRel = AssetEntryAssetCategoryRelLocalServiceUtil.updateAssetEntryAssetCategoryRel(assetEntryAssetCategoryRel);
                    
                }
```

I had assetentry and assetcategory object
This works fine for me